# ¿Como puedo contar MENORES Y MAYORES en un arreglo?

Tags: array, c

ya que estoy horas pensando este problema.

Ejercicio:
"Contar cuántas ventas menores a una cifra ENVIADA POR PARAMETRO, y cuántas mayores a esa cifra, hay en el arreglo."

En principio, dejo como mi logica.
Creo que podría llegar a agregar algo más.

```
int contarPrecios(int M[], int validos, int cifra){

  int i = 0;
  int cont = 0;

  while(validos < cifra && validos > cifra){

        if(validos < cifra){
          
             cont += 1;
         }

  }


  return cont;
```

}

Comment: y cuál es tu pregunta sobre ese código? digamos que acá no hacemos review del código, somos otros como tú que escribimos código y ayudamos a otros a resolver sus problemas. Acá, sin embargo, no nos has contado cuál es el error o problema

Comment: @alfabravo Buenas, quería saber si la lógica esta bien, o que debería cambiar, o hacer un código más optimo, para retornar las ventas menores a esa cifra y las mayores a cierta cifra. Muchas gracias por responder.

Comment: Una pregunta, y has probado tu codigo? Si
funciona? Aunque aqui no se hacen preguntas de
code review, puedes esperar algunas respuestas, ya
que no tenemos un sitio de code review en español
(al menos eso recuerdo de alguna pregunta en
meta). Pero para esperar a que te digan como
puedes mejorar tu codigo, primero tienes que tener
un codigo que funcione, y estoy bastante seguro de
que el codigo que publiaste no funciona (al menos para lo que dices que tiene
que hacer.)

Comment: @Pablochaches Si lo probé y se rompe, pero voy a tratar de darle una vuelta más al problemas, muchas gracias por la respuesta tan pronta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void MiMetodo (int arreglo[], int cifra) 
{
    int mayores = 0;
    int menores = 0;
    int iguales = 0;
    int tam = sizeof(arreglo) / sizeof(arreglo[0]);

    for(int i = 0; i < tam; i++)
    {
       if(arreglo[i] < cifra)
       {
          menores++;
       }
       else if(cifra == arreglo[i])
       {
          iguales++;
       }
       else if(arreglo[i] > cifra)
       {
          mayores++;
       }

       //Imprimir variable mayores
       //Imprimir variable menores
       //Imprimir variable iguales
    }
```

**Nota:** Incorporé también los elementos que son iguales a la cifra dada.

Se declaran tres variables:

**mayores:** para contar los valores mayores.

**menores:** para contar los valores menores.

**iguales:** para contar los valores iguales.

Se hace un **ciclo for** que va recorriendo todos los elementos del arreglo, si se encuentra un elemento mayor que el parámetro pasado se incrementa la **variable mayores**.

Si se encuentra un elemento igual que el parámetro pasado se incrementa la **variable iguales**.

Si se encuentra un elemento menor que el parámetro pasado se incrementa la **variable menores**.

Por último se imprimen todas los valores de cada variable.

Comment: @Pablochaches, arreglado, gracias

Comment: @Japv Muchísimas gracias, le estuve dando un par de vueltas y pude llegar a algo, gracias nuevamente.

Comment: @Pablochaches Gracias por la ayuda, le di un par de vueltas al problema y creo que lo tengo.

Comment: @Japv Estimado, solo a modo informativo, creo que tu respuesta te quedó incompleta al final.

Comment: @TomuRain, hola, puede decirme pq para arreglarla

Comment: @Japv al final dice "Si se encuentra un elemento" y quedó inconcluso, no?

Comment: @TomuRain, cierto, arreglado, gracias